How to make boxed headers in imakeidx
I am very interested in making my index headers look like those in this answer from 2017: Sample. The MWE from this answer is no longer available, so I was hoping to seek help in a new question.
Here is my current .ist file:
headings_flag 1

heading_prefix "\n\\centering\\large%
\\noindent\\textbf{"heading_suffix "}\\par\\nopagebreak\n"

item_0 "\n \\item \\small "

delim_0 " \\dotfill "
delim_1 " \\dotfill "
delim_2 " \\dotfill "


welcome! do you mean .ist rather than .idx? the .idx is different and you shouldn't edit it because it gets rewritten all the time.

Yes, I meant .ist. Sorry! Fixed the original post.
